# How can a bound variable be passed via render?

Tags: ember.js

How can a bound variable be passed through too a view via render helper:

```
{{render "myRender" model varA='helloRender' varB=controller.otherData}}
```

varA is passed through, but varB is not: [jsbin to illustrate](http://jsbin.com/tomiwa/14/).

Alternatively how can dynamic context (other than the model) be passed through to either the view or the controller?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here [in the source render](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/4445be038bd839a1559020db5677b211dd3f1e9c/packages/ember-routing-handlebars/lib/helpers/render.js#L88) helper can take only three parameters, and the third one mean to be an object of options, which will be used to create new controller and doesn't have an intention to pass values as you expect.

Edit

based on your edit, actually the options are for creating new context with the passed options hash, and hopefully the source would help you to get what you need.

Comment: This answer does not seem accurate as render can accept many variables passed through (I think the options argument is for a hash of options).  I'll update the jsbin to illustrate. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Render from the template is intended to be `templateName` `optionalModel`, the other syntax isn't a supported syntax, what you're likely experiencing is leakage from handlebars itself into the view, the options argument is the model itself.